# How do I seal off my garage?

Tags: garage

We run a dehumidifier full time in our garage. In the summer we empty it once a day. A couple weeks ago I thought there has to be a reason we need to dehumidify. I found out that our garage has an opening to the outside. I want to seal this off but I don't know how.

The spot that is open is just above the poured concrete walls. This was constructed in 2007. I don't understand why they would leave this open to the outside.

How can I seal this off in a way that looks professional?

This picture is where the garage is not sealed off above the concrete wall.

[image]

This picture is where the garage is sealed off above the wall.

[image]

Comment: Is there a requirement in your area that the garage is vented?  Where are you, and are there any appliances in the garage?

Comment: There is only an electric hot water heater. I'm in Jefferson County AL. I don't know if that is a requirement for building codes; digging into this now. As of 2014 my city has adopted the International Building Code 2006 edition.

Comment: Why are you running a dehumidifier in your garage? Garages are typically uninsulated, unconditioned space. Are you turning it in to a living space?

Comment: When I first moved in my boxes were molding. There were some water issues when it rained for days on end. I sorted out the water issue and have been afraid to turn off the dehumidifier. Plus it's humid down there in the summer. Note, we're not turning it into a living space but do enjoy spending time in the unconditioned space.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question, I'm making a comment rather than an answer.  I would guess that you'll want that ventilation to remain to prevent CO or other fumes from building up in your garage.  You don't mention anything, but your comments make me think that your garage might be underground, which would be a problem to keep dry anyway.  Since it appears that your dehumidifier is needed continually to keep it dry.  Perhaps consider a condensate pump to take the condensate from your dehumidifier and automatically pump it out and to a drain so you don't need to empty it manually.